# No errors generated in GCC when including multiple source files

Tags: c, gcc

I have a project with the following layout:

```bash
$ ls
foo_bar  foo_bar-merged

$ ls foo_bar/
bar.c  baz.h  foo.c

$ ls foo_bar-merged/
foo_bar-merged.c

$ cat foo_bar/foo.c
#include "baz.h"
int foo(int a)
{
    return a + 1;
}

$ cat foo_bar/bar.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "baz.h"
void print_int(int a)
{
    printf_baz(stdout, "%d\n", a);
}

$ cat foo_bar/baz.h
#ifndef BAZ_H
#define BAZ_H
#ifdef _STDIO_H
void printf_baz(FILE *, const char *, ...);
#endif
#endif

$ cat foo_bar-merged/foo_bar-merged.c
#include "foo_bar/foo.c"
#include "foo_bar/bar.c"
```

When compiling `foo_bar-merged/foo_bar-merged.c`, one would expect a warning or error due to `printf_baz` not being declared in `baz.h` the first time the header is loaded. However, running

```
$ gcc -Wall -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -I./foo_bar -c foo_bar-merged/foo_bar-merged.c -o foo_bar-merged/foo_bar-merged.o
```

does not generate an error. However, modifying `foo_bar-merged/foo_bar-merged.c` to

```c
#include "foo.c"
#include "bar.c"
```

and compiling with the same command *does* generate the expected error

```
In file included from foo_bar-merged/foo_bar-merged.c:2:
./foo_bar/bar.c: In function ‘print_int’:
./foo_bar/bar.c:6:5: error: implicit declaration of function ‘printf_baz’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
    6 |     printf_baz(stdout, "%d\n", a);
      |     ^~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
```

Why is this?

Comment: Do you know about the concept of [*translation units*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming))? This is the basic unit that the compiler actually works on. It's simply a single source file and *all included files*. Because `foo_bar-merged` is a single translation unit, that also contains the contents of `baz.h`, the declaration is there, ready to be used.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Yes, but `bar.c` is included after `foo.c`, and therefore `baz.h` is loaded once, and that is without `stdio.h`. Hence, `fprintf_baz` should not be declared at all, and with `-Werror=implicit-function-declaration` it should generate an error.

Comment: It would have been better if we could see a [mre] instead of a description of the code. With that said, traditionally C have historically been very lacking when it comes to function declarations. If none is found when a function is called, the compiler *deduces* the arguments from the call. If a declaration is found later, the compiler doesn't have to say anything if it more or less matches the deduced guess. This behavior depends on the used C standard, as it has changed over the years. GCC still defaults to a rather old standard IIRC.

Comment: I could not reproduce the problem. Could you add the CFLAGS `-save-temps -dumpbase save-foo` options and examine the `save-foo.i` file to check whether `fprintf_baz` is declared (or defined) before it is called?

Comment: @IanAbbott Please see my edit

Comment: You shouldn't check `#ifdef _STDIO_H` because that is implementation-defined. You should define and check your own macro.

Comment: @IanAbbott Assume it is some other header then. That it is exactly `stdio.h` is not important to the my case.

Comment: I can't reproduce `gcc -Wall -Werror=implicit-function-declaration -I./foo_bar -c foo_bar-merged/foo_bar-merged.c -o foo_bar-merged/foo_bar-merged.o` gives me `foo_bar/foo.c: No such file or directory`. There is no `-I.`. Are you sure you are using the files and commands you presented? `tree` is useful to present directory tree. Consider making a Makefile to reproduce. If I compile with `-I.` then I get the same error for both `foo_bar-merged.c`. so can't reproduce.

Comment: I got the same error as @KamilCuk

Comment: @KamilCuk I am using GCC version 13.2.1, what version are you using? I think I problems before with GCC not searching parent directory, but mine appear to do that nowadays.

Comment: I tested with gcc13.2.1 on archlinux.

Comment: OK rather than using `#ifdef _STDIO_H`, in **foo_bar/baz.h**, use `#ifdef STDIO_H` as in the original question, and add `#define STDIO_H` before `#include "baz.h"` in **foo_bar/bar.c**. That at least eliminates the use of implementation-defined macros.

Comment: The first version, with e.g. `#include "foo_bar/foo.c"`, should not build at all, as it should not find the file to include. When including with `""` the compiler will first look in the same directory as the current source file, and then the include path list. And it will look for *exactly* `foo_bar/foo.c` with that directory prefix. Since you add `foo_bar` to the include search path list, the compiler will look for `foo_bar/foo_bar/foo.c` which can't be found. Perhaps GCC also looks in the working directory as well?

Comment: To find out more, please build with the `-v` (verbose) option, so you can see more details, and the exact list of paths the compiler will look for include files.

Comment: Is `foo_bar-merged.c` in the upper directory not inside a subdirectory? Even if, the error "implicit declaration of function printf_baz" is the same in both cases anyway. All suggests you may using different files.

Comment: The first version needs `-I.` instead of `-I./foo_bar`. The second version needs `-I./foo_bar` (or `-Ifoo_bar`).